# Issue with Painless Script Elasticsearch Watcher

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elasticsearch-painless

I am creating a watcher in elasticsearch that reports when we havent had new entry or events in the index for 10 minutes this is further split out by looking at the source field in the entry.

I am only getting the last 10 mins of the index and seeing which source is not present in the buckets.

to do this I am first creating a list of all the source types we receive then creating a list from the bucket keys returned. Then I want to compare the lists to see which one is missing to then pass this into the message.

I am getting a generic error for the for loop. Any feedback is helpful quite new to elastic and painless so could be something simple I've missed.

```
"transform": {
          "script": {
            "source": """String vMessage = 'Clickstream data has been loaded although there are no iovation records from the following source in the last 10 mins:

';if(ctx.payload.clickstream.hits.total > 0 && ctx.payload.iovation.aggregations.source.buckets.size() < 3) { source_list = ['wintech', 'login', 'clickstream']; source_array = new String[] for (source in ctx.payload.iovation.aggregations.source.buckets){ source_array.add(source.key);  } for (key in source_list){ if (!source_array.contains(key){ vMessage += '<ul><li>' + key + '</li></ul>';}  } }return [ 'message': vMessage ];""",
            "lang": "painless"
          }
        },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured it out after digging through more documentation.

I was declaring my lists incorrectly. To declare a list it needs to be in format as below.

```
 List new_list = new ArrayList();
```

This solved my issue and now the transform script works as expected.

```
"""String vMessage = 'Clickstream data has been loaded although there are no iovation records from the following source in the last 10 mins:

';if(ctx.payload.clickstream.hits.total > 0 && ctx.payload.iovation.aggregations.source.buckets.size() < 3) { List source_list = new ArrayList(['wintech', 'login', 'clickstream']); List source_array = new ArrayList(); for (source in ctx.payload.iovation.aggregations.source.buckets){ source_array.add(source.key);  } for (key in source_list){ if (!source_array.contains(key)){ vMessage += '<ul><li>' + key + '</li></ul>';}  } }return [ 'message': vMessage ];""",
```